# Load matrix-type ascii file in numpy, very slow

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am new in python. I have an ascii file (6000 KB) matrix-type and I would like to import it in numpy conserving the same shape, i.e. having a numpy-matrix. I am doing that by using the code reported below. The code executed gives a matrix (1456L, 2048L) but to load one file it takes 20 seconds. How can I speed this up? 
 
Thank you in advance

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

    def load_matrix_from_file(f):
       import types

       if type(f) == types.StringType:
          fo = open(f, 'r')
          matrix = load_matrix_from_file(fo)
          fo.close()
          return matrix

       elif type(f) == types.FileType:
          file_content = f.read().strip()
          file_content = file_content.replace('\r\n', ';')
          file_content = file_content.replace('\n', ';')
          file_content = file_content.replace('\r', ';')

       return np.matrix(file_content)

       raise TypeError('f must be a file object or a file name.')

    data3 = load_matrix_from_file('file_name.asc')
```

Comment: The point is you aren't loading the matrix in numpy, you are loading it in python, then converting it to a numpy matrix. Have you looked at numpy.loadtxt?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works much faster with numpy.loadtxt beside it is an ascii file.

Comment: i would save as a binary using `np.save` and use `np.load` from now on.

Comment: @talonmies you could post your comment as an answer...